# Parent onClick is not triggered when the child element is clicked inside button

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a `dropdown-button` component which has a click lister. The button has some text and icon. The click event is triggered if we click the button carefully on the outline and not on the text or icon. Here is my component:

```
<template lang="html">
<div>
  <button class="button dropbtn" @click="toggleDropdown">
    <span>{{ name }}</span>
    <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></span>
  </button>
  <div v-show="visible" class="dropdown-content is-primary-important">
    <slot>
    </slot>
  </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['name'],
  data: function() {
    return {
      visible: false
    }
  },
  mounted: function() {
    this.hideDropdownOnClick();
  },
  methods: {
    toggleDropdown: function() {
      // trigged on click of the button
      // make the dropdown visible
      console.log("toggling dropdown");
      this.visible = !this.visible;
    },
    hideDropdownOnClick: function() {
      window.onclick = (event) => {
        console.log(event.target);
        if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
          console.log("here", this.visible);
          this.visible = false;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style lang="css">
/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
  min-width: 140px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
</style>
```

I feel that I am missing something very basic here, can someone help me with this? Thanks.

> Edit

It seems like a bug with the browser as the answer to this question says:
[Button element not firing click event when clicking on button text and releasing off it (but still inside the button)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15679787/button-element-not-firing-click-event-when-clicking-on-button-text-and-releasing)

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't think I understand what you said. Should the child items return a true onClick?

Comment: @aks your code is working for me... https://jsfiddle.net/jwtmL0fd/

Comment: Oops, its vue, I am not aware of the behavior. For js it should be bubble to parent if you are not preventing it by stopPropogation.

Comment: @SLYcee it doesn't! please try clicking on the text, in my browser `chrome` it is not working!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Adding this CSS rule fixes the issue for me:

```
span {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: This is by far the easiest and most effective answer. Thank you.

Comment: Another classic example where the accepted answer is much more complex than a simple solution.

Answer (score 4):

When You click in span its toggled twice:) once by toggleDropdown method,
second by windows onclick handler.

here is working example: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fhuu26ro/)

```
<template id="tmp">
  <div>
  <button class="button dropbtn" @click="toggleDropdown">
    <span>{{ name }}</span>
    <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></span>
  </button>
  <div v-show="visible" class="dropdown-content is-primary-important">
    <slot>
    </slot>
  </div>
</div>
</template>

<div id="x">
  <tmp name="my name">
     <span>toggle me!</span>
  </tmp>
</div>

Vue.component('tmp', {
template: '#tmp',

props: ['name'],
data: function() {
return {
  visible: false
}
},
mounted: function() {
this.hideDropdownOnClick();
},
methods: {
toggleDropdown: function() {
  // trigged on click of the button
  // make the dropdown visible
  console.log("toggling dropdown");
  this.visible = !this.visible;
}
}
});

new Vue({
el: '#x',
data: function(){
    return {
    name: 'myName'
  }
}
});
```

edit: 
if you don't want to use clickaway here is small directive to detect clicks outside of element:

```
var VueClickOutSide = {

    bind: function(el, binding, vNode) {
        var bubble = binding.modifiers.bubble;
        var handler = function(e) {
            if (bubble || (!el.contains(e.target) && el !== e.target)) {
                binding.value(e);
            }
        }
        el.__vueClickOutside__ = handler;
        document.addEventListener('click', handler);
    },

    unbind: function (el, binding, vNode) {
        document.removeEventListener('click', el.__vueClickOutside__);
        el.__vueClickOutside__ = null;
    }
};
```

You just have to register that directive:

```
Vue.directive('click-outside', VueClickOutSide)
```

And use it in template:

```
 v-click-outside:delay="hideDropdownOnClick"
```

Comment: Ya, what you say is right. Can you please suggest a way that when we click outside then the dropdown can be hidden?

Comment: as SLYcee mentioned u can use clickaway.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [vue-clickaway](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-clickaway) to hide dropdown when click outside :

1. `$ npm install vue-clickaway --save`
2. `import { mixin as clickaway } from 'vue-clickaway';`
3. `export default {
      mixins: [ clickaway ],
      ... the rest of your code ...`
4. You put `v-clickaway="visible = false"` in your root div of your `dropdown-button` component.

Answer (score 0):

On click you show and immediately hide list.
You click text or icon (they are "span"),

```
this.visible = !this.visible;
```

then code goes to **window.onclick** where

```
if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn'))
```

and your spans dont have this class. So you set

```
 this.visible = false;
```

Change check to

```
    if (!event.target.closest('.dropbtn'))
```